# Reload webview from app delegate not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I want to reload a webview in my view controller when my app comes to the foreground. I have created a view controller object in my application delegate's `-applicationWillEnterForeground` and `-applicationDidBecomeActive` methods. But I am not able to refresh my webview.

Comment: show your code of `applicationDidBecomeActive` and `applicationwillEnterForeground`.

Comment: MainViewController *mainViewCtrler = [[MainViewController alloc] init];
[mainViewCtrler connectToServer];                                 I have reloaded the web view in connectToServer method.

Answer (score 0):

applicationWillEnterForeground may not be the best way to do it.

In the class that contains the webView add a notification method like below

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
 selector:@selector(didEnterForeground)
 name:UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification
 object:nil];

-(void) didEnterForeGround
{
//[webView reload];
}
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your reply. I have done that too. But still it's not working. Here is my code                                    -(id)init
{
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(reloadWebView:) name:UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification object:nil];
        NSLog(@"Reload webview");
    
    return self;
}

-(void)reloadWebView:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    [locationServicewebView reload];
}

Comment: Did the notification generate properly give some NSLog there and test or Try to reload webView in viewWillAppear.

Answer (score 0):

When your application comes to Foreground is app is active state , in particular view controller on viewdidload or viewdidAppear Method [WEBVIEW ReloadData]; thats it , you donot wan to do any thing in appdelegate class